# Chrome Extension interacting with page styling (Bootstrap container missing left padding)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following problem in my page (which uses bootstrap), which I also notice on the Official bootstrap examples: ( http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ )

Even though the `.container` class has:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

15 pixels of left and right padding, in reality, for some reason I can't pinpoint, the left padding seems to be halved.

In my case, where I set

```
$grid-gutter-width: 15px;
```

the actually padding-left of the container, even though it is reported as "7.5px" which is correct, seems to be 0.

[image]

Comment: Can you link a relevant JSFiddle link please ?

Comment: @Zeratops http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

That is really strange... in my it works just fine.
When I disable it, it works correctly aswell.

The only think that I saw, is that you are cutting a part of the browser.
see the yellow rectangle that contains div.container 345px x 3427px

Comment: it seems that when I use incognite mode, the padding is correctly reported, so it is a problem with my Chrome or one of the plugins. Good luck finding what :(

Comment: it was a chrome extension that I removed and the problem's fixed.

Comment: glad that you did it!

Comment: yeah I accepted your answer because you helped me suspect a computer-related-problem.

Comment: ty! at least i could show you that the bootstrap is right hahahaha ^^